# testing existing model with different population?

Tags: python, testing, machine-learning, model

hi guys i have a machine learning problem, this is about classification

so i have 2 datasets let's called it data1 and data2,

data1 is about historical data(data 1 have 50000 row with 30 columns)
data2 is a new data(data 2 have 150 row with 10 columns(this 10 columns also exist in data 1)

what i want to do is:

i want to use data1 machine learning model  to TEST IT into data2 to do a classification problem

=====================================================================

what i have done:

1. because of the difference i only took 10 columns of data 2 for data1 to train the model, so for data1 before training i have 50000 row with 10 columns
2. i modeled data1(based on that 10 feature ) and get a very good score(ROC/AUC, accuracy, precission is above 90%)
3. i tried split test training, Crossvalidate for data1 ONLY and the result is very good

BUT..the problem is

4. when i tried to test the model of data1 to data2 ...the result is become very bad

so im asking about what happened here? am i getting bad result because of data1 and data2 is a different population?

can i have a good theory to match my assumption or anything if im mistaken. thank you

Comment: Check for overfitting. It's hard to tell what is the difference between the two datasets based on your description. If the trends in historic data are very different from new data prove this by plotting graphs to compare them.

Comment: data 1 model is free from overfitting. by the way, i found my problem its called covariate shift(data1 and data2 distribution is different) .im currently looking how to overcome this problem. if you know or have any good refference in python that would be great

Comment: you cannot really use this training set for your test set, here are some techniques in a good article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-to-do-when-your-training-and-testing-data-come-from-different-distributions-d89674c6ecd8/ , but if you need to predict data2, you cannot use data1 as training for it...they are to different

Comment: hi PV8. yeah that's the case . the problem is. Data2 is new costumer and Data1 is old costumer, i need to classified new costumer  based on Data1 model.  The distribution data1 and data2 obviously different so its not possible right?